# Given a number of vertical or horizontal segments and the coordinates of their endpoints(x1,x2,y1,y2) how many intersections do we have?

Tags: c++

With the given data(number if segments) and their coordinates, we are sure that they are either vertical or horizontal. How many intersections between all of them do we have ?

Comment: That sounds more like a mathematical than a programming problem.

Comment: Short answer: we have N intersections.

Comment: Consider asking at [mathematics.se], but read their [How to Ask pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and formulate your question accordingly. As written this question would be quickly placed on hold.

Answer (score 0):

### Idea: write a program!!!

Split the data into horizontal and vertical.

Now sort the data sets each.

That makes the intersection problem trivial.

Now you can efficiently enumerate all intersections.

Isn't it rest what you can do *if* you write some code?